# Parsing a whole tag by lxml.html

Tags: python-requests, python-3.4, lxml.html

I'm new to lxml and want to parse a page retrieved by "requests".
My html is this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 class="entry-title">
    <a href="http://a.com" rel="bookmark">
    bla bla bla
    </a>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to have a string that looks like this:

```
"""<h1 class="entry-title">
    <a href="http://google.com" rel="bookmark">
    bla bla bla
    </a>
</h1>"""
```

what would be the code in python 3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
from lxml.html import document_fromstring
from lxml.html import tostring
doc = document_fromstring(YOUR_HTML_STRING)
h1 = tostring(doc.xpath("//h1")[0])
```

Comment: am getting the <h1> fine. thanks for that. But is "tostring" always return in bytes ?(im geting {b'<h1 class="entry-title">\n<a href="http://a.com" rel="bookmark">\nbla bla bla\n</a>\n</h1>\n'})
to make it str do i have to write `print h1.decode(encoding="utf-8")` or something? or i can just use in "bytes"?

Comment: @nazmussaif, i am using something like h1.encode("utf-8")